# LNK1104: cannot open file 'kernel32.lib' while linking openCV

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2012, linker, linker-errors

I am trying to use OPENCV on visual C++ 2012 as a blank project. All the libraries are set and  include paths are correct, however I get the "LNK1104: cannot open file 'kernel32.lib'" error while debugging the code snippet. prior to the error there is also a warning indicating:

Warning 1   warning MSB8003: Could not find WindowsSDKDir variable from the registry.  TargetFrameworkVersion or PlatformToolset may be set to an invalid version number.   C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets

are they related?

Comment: It's not a problem with OpenCV, but with WindowsSDK. Fix it(google the warning) and everything should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Make you have in VC++ directories (Right click project, Click Property Page),

- Include Directories: $(IncludePath)
- List item Library Directories: $(LibraryPath)